# Visual Studio 2017 oracle not shown in EF Data Source

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, odp.net, odac

Oracle Database not shown when creating Ado.Net Data Model entity framework database first new connection selected

I setup odac and Oracle Developer Tools for vs 2017.
Also added oracle managed data access entity framework references from nuget.
Does anyone know solution for vs 2017?
Screen shot below thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install ODP.NET to get it to work. See this documentation from Oracle:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html

Answer (score 0):

During the component selection of the install, **Uncheck “Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio” option**.
This has worked for me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG7X9.png)